# Should a question edit be rolled back if it appears to be a follow-up to an answer?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks, forums

I have, on occasion, rolled back a user's edit to their own question when it appears to be a new follow-up question - as if to emulate the mechanics of a discussion forum or chat room.

[Here's an old example that happens to have my face all over it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960548)  (I make no claims to the quality of my answer.)

I've done it other times when I wasn't otherwise involved.

---

If an answer *appears* to be acceptable, and a subsequent edit to the question *appears* to introduce new questions, based on that answer (thus invalidating the answer):

Is is appropriate to roll back the edit?  Comment that there's a more appropriate mechanism for asking a new question?

Should it matter if the question was outright replaced with a new question or if it was *amended*, as it was in my link above?  Is it my business even if I'm uninvolved with the question/answers?

Comment: I would do the same what you have done.

Comment: Any edit that invalidates preexisting answers should be rolled back.

Comment: A followup to an answer is not such a problem (if the user says "I took the idea of so-and-so's answer, wrote this code, and found that it worked in 96% of the cases but failed in that corner case").  But if the question is changed to ask for something new or beyond the original question, then a rollback is appropriate.